# Opening a GUI program in full screen from command line invocation

Tags: windows-10, command-line, gui, fullscreen, git-bash

Specifically, I want to have the *git-bash* command prompt opened in *full-screen mode* upon startup of Windows 10.

[image: git-bash GUI]

To this end, I have added as shortcut of the program to Windows' startup folder; it opens automatically upon startup, as expected. But its window is not maximized.

My first guess was to add a certain (yet unknown) *option* to the invocation of the shortcut by modifying its *source* invocation `<path>/git-bash.exe --option` by accessing the *settings* of the shortcut, as seen below. But, I don't know if such an option is available. **Is there a way to uncover the available options to an .exe program, in Windows?**

[image: Settings of shortcut]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full screen mode tends to not work with most applications, but you can try this alternative. Within the shortcut properties, on the same screen you linked above, under run: select maximised from the pull-down menu. A general rule with most shortcuts is to click on advanced and run as administrator as well.

[image: Maximsed]

Comment: Suprisingly, this does not work; I've selected the *Maximized* option and rebooted; it doesn't open in full screen. However, I have not resorted to running the shortcut in as adimistrator, since I don't want to run into (unintentional) privilege issues later on.

Answer (score 2):

I have resorted --- worked around --- to opening the options menu of *git bash*, which I just noticed.

In here, I've adjusted the default window size to "full screen" coordinates:

[image: Manual GUI options menu adjustment screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can add in `%userprofile%\.minttyrc` following settings to start `git-bash.exe` **always maximized**:

> `Window=max`

or

> `Window=full`

to start `git-bash.exe` **always in full screen**.

## Alternative

Create a shortcut with the following content:

> `"%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" --window max`

or

> `"%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" --window full`

Answer (score 0):

Edit .minttyrc file in user folder:

```
 cd ~
 nano .minttyrc
```

Add the line:

```
Window=max
```

Save the file

```
(Control + O)
```

Close the bash and open it again to see the results.